# Linq query - find strings based upon first letter b/w two ranges

Tags: c#, linq, letters

We have a list containing names of countries. We need to find names of countries from list b/w two letters. Like names of all countries with name starting b/w A-G and so on. We create following linq query but its ugly.

```
var countryAG = from elements in countryList
where elements.StartsWith("A") || 
elements.StartsWith("B") || 
elements.StartsWith("C") || 
elements.StartsWith("D") || 
elements.StartsWith("E") || 
elements.StartsWith("F") || 
elements.StartsWith("G") || 
elements.StartsWith("H") 
select elements;
```

where countryList is created in C#

```
List< string> countryList = new List< string>();
```

Any help or any other efficient way to accomplish above task?

Comment: Can we assume that the country names are in English and we can use English sort order?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var countryAG = from elements in countryList
                where elements[0] >= 'A' && elements[0] <= 'H'
                select elements;
```

Chars are just numbers really, thus you can compare them as such

Comment: That query won't compile, you forgot `select`.

Comment: Thanks @Steven but following error during build:A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Comment: @svick, where i should add select?

Comment: Sorry, thats what I get for writing directly inside the browser :-) Thnx svick

Answer (score 3):

I can't test it right now, but I would try

```
countryList.Where((s) => s[0] <= 'A' && s[0] >= 'G');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a prefix list and then use the prefix list for comparison - this way you can easily use different prefix lists based on what range you are interested in:

```
 List<string> prefixList = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
 var countryAG = countryList.Where( x=> prefixList.Any( p => x.StartsWith(p)));
```

Comment: Thanks @Broken but it is same as my current approach. I am not interested in writing all English alphabets.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
char[] startingLetters = new char[] {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'};
var countryAG = 
    from elements in countryList 
    where elements.IndexOfAny(startingLetters, 0, 1) == 0 
    select elements;
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wh7x3fs.aspx) for information on `IndexOfAny`.

Comment: Thanks @Yahia but it is same as my current approach. I am not interested in writing all English alphabets.

Comment: sorry to read that - you asked for a more efficient way... I would bet that the query from my answer runs faster than the one you are currently using and thus I suggested it...

Comment: Sorry @Yahia. I ignore efficiency aspect as I was constructing on "making things simple" and ignore "efficient" part. Sorry again. Also, do we have any way of "making things simple and efficient". Scenario is simple, we have list of countries name and we have to divide them among A-G, I-P and Q-Z. I thought Linq is quick and easy. Your thoughts please.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this code:

```
var start = "a";
var end = "g";
var regex = new Regex(string.Format("^[{0}-{1}]", start, end));
var result = list.Where(x => regex.Match(x.ToLowerInvariant()).Success);
```

'start' and 'end' are static as an example.

Comment: Using regex sounds interesting. I will give this a try. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Instead of `Match().Success`, you can use `IsMatch()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have two extension functions:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> Range(char start, char end)
{
  return Enumerable.Range((int)start, (int)end - (int)start + 1).Select(i => (char)i);
}
```

which creates a range of characters, and

```
public static bool In(this string source, IEnumerable<string> collection)
{
  return collection.Contains(source);
}
```

which is just the inverse of `Contains`, mostly for readability.

Together I can do:

`where elements[0].In(Range('a', 'f')))`

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> mainList = new List<string>()
        {
           "A","B","DD","EE","F","G","EE","CC","DD","Q","R","CC"
        };

        List<string> searchList = new List<string>() { "DD", "EE", "CC" };

        var finalList = mainList.Where(x => searchList.Any(p => p == x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Two ways to filter list according to first letter of string:

1. `list = list.Where(x => x.WordText.ToUpper().StartsWith(Character));`
2. `list = list.Where(x =>  Regex.IsMatch(x.WordText.ToUpper().Substring(0, 1), Character));`