# With Linq search the words that start from H to L

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio, linq-to-entities

In my LinQ query I have to search words that start from H to L.
This is my code:

```
var Artists = context.GetTable<Artist>();
var leftOuterJoinQuery =
            from arti in Artists
            where arti.Name.StartsWith("H")//to L
```

var Artists contains table with all artists from my Database.

Someone knows how resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and expected results?

Comment: @Magnus i did some search and i see linq to entities does not support regex. so i deleted the answer.

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216883/linq-query-find-strings-based-upon-first-letter-b-w-two-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you can use relational operators for this (`>`, `<`, etc.), but C# doesn't accept `stringA > stringB`. Fortunately, EF translates `String.CompareTo` into relational operators, so you can do:

```
where arti.Name.CompareTo("H") >= 0 && c.Name.CompareTo("M") < 0)
```

This will be translated into

```sql
WHERE ([Extent1].[Name] >= 'H') AND ([Extent1].[Name] < 'M')
```

Note that it depends on the database collation of the `Name` column whether or not case sensitivity is accounted for.

Comment: very nice. i think the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

you could have a list of letters and then filter on that - e.g:

```
var letters = new[] {"H","I", "J", "K", "L"};
var Artists = context.GetTable<Artist>().Where (a => letters.Any (l => a.Name.StartsWith(l)));
```